# How to make a button work(Google signin) in navigation header activity?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, google-signin

I'm new in android development, I used the navigation drawer activity template.  I followed the tutorial by firebase to put in the code and made some change. My question is, I made a signin button in the navigation header, I would like to click the button then trigger the Google signin function. I put that code in a new java class, and how can I use MainActivity.java to make it work? many thanks.

[image]

NavHeadMainActivity.java

```
    public class NavHeaderMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private NavHeaderMainBinding mBinding;

    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(signInListener);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }
    private Button.OnClickListener signInListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    signIn();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
//                            Snackbar.make(mBinding.mainLayout, "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {

        if (user != null) {
            mBinding.eMail.setText(user.getEmail());
            mBinding.userName.setText(user.getUid());

            signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            mBinding.signOutAndDisconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mBinding.eMail.setText(null);
            mBinding.userName.setText(null);

            signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            mBinding.signOutAndDisconnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private Button signInBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    signInBtn = (Button) headerView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInBtn.setOnClickListener(signInBtnListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

private Button.OnClickListener signInBtnListener =new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,NavHeaderMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
}
```